# Randomize the height on the z-axis for distributed points in Blender 3.0 using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying randomize the z location of each point distributed on a plane. Since 3.0, you cannot use the Attribute Randomize node. I tried using Random Value + Combine XYZ into the transform translation node but that didn't work.

[image: Hedge Plants]

[image: Distributed Objects]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Transform* node is for moving geometries as a whole, not one by one, and doesn't accept field inputs (diamond-shaped socket), only singular values (circular socket). You can use the *Translate Instances* node and feed it with a *Random Value > Combine XYZ—Z* setup instead:

[image]

Or a *Random Value* in *Vector* mode, of course:

[image]