# How to randomize instances position?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, random

I can randomize the rotation and scale with the instance node but what about position? I wanna scatter it along the z axis using random value.

[image]

Comment: You can use ["Translate Instances"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/259378/2214) node at the end of tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a *Set Position* Node (after the *Instance on Points*). Connect a *Random Value* node to the Z position of a *Combine XYZ* node and use the output as the *Offset* on the *Set Position* Node.

[image: Scale]

You can also use the setup shown below with a *Vector Math (Multiply)* node multiplying the random value on the Z-axis with a Scalar to control how much the spread goes "up".

Comment: Thank you so much man

Comment: I was curious, why did you use Vector for Random node since you need to feed just Z axis (so Float can handle it). How X,Y participate on result? ... because I can see difference.

Answer (score 3):

> The solution of *@ChristopherBennett* works in principle, but it is not optimal!

To achieve a position shift of instances exclusively on the *Z-axis*, you should use in this case directly after `Instance on Points` the node `Translate Instances`.

Since you only need a translation on the *Z-axis*, you only need one additional node: `Random Value`.

This one should be set to *Vector*, and should return a vector between $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,x)$:

[image]

By the way, in the best case you move the points themselves, where instantiation is to take place. This can save resources:

[image]

[image]